# LWC - Help text won't disappear on lookup

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup

I'm having an issue where the help text won't disappear when using a lookup field in my LWC. It only appears when the user hovers over the little help text bubble, but it lasts forever and I'm not sure how to go about resolving this.

Since lookup fields aren't able to be used directly like other field types, it's contained in a `lightning-record-edit-form` and a `lightning-input-field`. If there's a way to simply not use the help text this way, I can't find it.

Also, due to the requirement of it being called by a button on the page layout, it's being contained in an Aura component that's inside of a Visualforce page, which I believe is also a part of the problem. My best guess is the layering of these page types is why it's appearing, but I don't believe there's any way around this setup.

[image: Picture of error]

Comment: I'm seeing this happen more over the past week or two. I'd looked to see if you had found an answer. I haven't found one yet but wanted to let you know you're not alone.

Comment: i also caught up this issue again & again recently,  i feel this starts from recent salesforce release.